# What is (and how to perform) action listing?

Tags: command-line

After performing a series of actions in Linux's terminal, I am supposed to perform a "listing" of them.

I couldn't find it online. All I can guess is that I am supposed to make the terminal print out a list of recently performed actions.

What command is used for doing something like this?

Comment: your online quest might meet with success if you stopped calling them actions and called them commands instead

Comment: Try `history` or `fc -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An “action in Linux's terminal” is presumably a **[command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_(computing))** that you typed at a **[shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing))** prompt.

Typical shells record a **history** of past commands. In bash, the commands [`fc` and `history`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Builtins) both display the history of recent commands; see the manual for available options. You can also navigate among past commands by pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd>, and [search](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Searching) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.